# Wrong number of Arguments error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm following a tutorial and building a small instagram clone with Rails 4.2.5

But I'm not sure why I keep on getting this Wrong number of arguments error.

[image: I am receiving this error]

EDIT: This is error message in a text format, it is present at Line 15:

```
13
14    def update
15        if @pic = Pic.update(pic_params)
16           redirect_to @pic, notice: "Congrats! Your picture was updated!"
17        else
18           render 'edit'
19        end
20    end
```

I have defined a private method 'pic_params' in my pics_controller that passes in 2 arguments, :title and :description.

And my update action passes in the pic_params function:

```
class PicsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_pic, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
    @pics = Pic.all.order("created_at DESC")
end

def show
end

def edit
end

def update
    if @pic = Pic.update(pic_params)
        redirect_to @pic, notice: "Congrats! Your picture was updated!"
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def new
    @pic = Pic.new
end

def create
    @pic = Pic.new(pic_params)
    if @pic.save
        redirect_to @pic, notice: "Yess! It worked!"
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end


private

def pic_params
    params.require(:pic).permit(:title, :description)
end

def find_pic
   @pic = Pic.find(params[:id])
end
```

end

And I know for sure my model also includes both of those columns..(title and description) according to my schema.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161218131012) do

create_table "pics", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "title"
 t.text     "description"
 t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
```

end

end

So why am I getting this error? There should be 2 arguments specified according to 'pic_params'!

If anyone can help, that'd be fantastic!

Comment: This sometimes happens if there are no pic-params coming through (ie you are just getting `nil`). Can you check your console-window/logfiles for what params are actually being passed to your controller?

Comment: Thank you Taryn, I just resolved the issue. :)

Comment: Please, post the error message instead of a picture of the error message. I cannot even read the error message on my phone. And I sure can't copy and paste it. What line does it appear in? What does it say?

Comment: I apologize, I have now written out the error message right under the link to the picture of the error. The error says "wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)" and it occurs at Line 15. I will take note of your advice for any future posts I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrong at `Pic.update(pic_params)`

`Pic` is a model, not object, you only use update with an object.

Plz try:

```
def update
  if @pic.update(pic_params)
    redirect_to @pic, notice: "Congrats! Your picture was updated!"
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah! Great catch! Thank you, Duyet.